# the error says "Function cannot be declared as view because this expression (potentially) modifies the state" how to fix it? in the last two lines

Tags: solidity

```
function selectWinner() public view returns(address)
     {
         require(msg.sender==manager);
         require(participants.length>=3);
         uint r=random();
         address payable winner;
         uint index = r % participants.length;
         winner=participants[index];
         winner.transfer(getBalance());
         participants=new address payable[](0);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are changing a state here.

```
function selectWinner() public view returns(address)
     {
         require(msg.sender==manager);
         require(participants.length>=3);
         uint r=random();
         address payable winner;
         uint index = r % participants.length;
         winner=participants[index];
         winner.transfer(getBalance());
         participants=new address payable[](0);  // <---- HERE
     }
```

when view functions are called, which enforces the state to stay unmodified as part of the EVM execution. ([solidity docs reference](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#view-functions))

When you have view or pure modifiers you can return the value but if you remove the view modifier best solution to get a value from the execution is using [event logs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#events), if you need the value to return do remove the state change

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simple: removing the word `view` from your function declaration. Because your function either modifying the state or having fund transfer:

```
function selectWinner() public returns(address) { 
 require(msg.sender==manager);
 ...
}
```